# MySQL STR_TO_DATE problem

Tags: mysql

I've got the following part of a query:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(g.Year,',',g.Month,',',g.Day),'%Y,%m,%d') AS HelpDate
```

g is a table of course. I know the values of g.Year, g.Month and g.Day all work fine because if I take out the STR_TO_DATE call and just use:

```
CONCAT(g.Year,',',g.Month,',',g.Day) AS HelpDate
```

it works fine. For some reason mysql breaks with the addition of the STR_TO_DATE. As far as I can tell this should work. I even tried hard coding the date just to force it to make sure I wasn't crazy:

```
STR_TO_DATE('2011,9,2','%Y,%m,%d') AS HelpDate
```

That didn't work either

## Edit:

Ok. So the reason STR_TO_DATE wouldn't work at all for me was because the server was running MySQL 4.0. I've since moved the database to a MySQL5 server. Now, here's my problem. STR_TO_DATE only works as long as I'm not trying to concatenate table references. For example, both of these work:

```
STR_TO_DATE('2011,9,2','%Y,%m,%d') AS HelpDate
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2011',',','9',',','2'),'%Y,%m,%d') AS HelpDate
```

However, this still does not:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(g.Year,',',g.Month,',',g.Day),'%Y,%m,%d') AS HelpDate
```

I get this error:

```
#1305 - FUNCTION db380975735.STR_TO_DATE does not exist
```

db38097573 is the name of the database

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the format `'%Y,%c,%e'`. `%m` and `%d` matches the month/day when it begins with a zero (it would match `2011,09,02`).

By the way, what's the point to store the year, month and day separately? Store it in a DATE type, and use the functions YEAR(), DAY() and MONTH() if necessary.

Comment: ah, thanks! And, yes it would make more sense to store it like that. Unfortunately this is an old database I didn't build. I'm just responsible for adding some functionality to the site.

Comment: @vincent there is a point, if you want to do some calculations on day/month/year. If you use DAY(date) etc you cannot put indexes

Comment: mkk: Most DBMS allow indexes on expressions, but you're right, MySQL doesn't.

Comment: Ok, still having problems. I even tried just a straight up select just like this:
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2011,9,2','%Y,%c,%e') AS HelpDate;
phpMyAdmin is spitting back:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('2011,9,2','%Y,%c,%e') AS HelpDate' at line 1

Comment: @LoneWorlfPR: I copy and pasted this query and it works correctly, I can't tell where the mistake is.

Comment: I think it's phpMyAdmin. I copy and pasted the example straight from dev.mysql.com documentation and it didn't work.

Comment: Well, figured it out. The server is running MySQL 4.0. STR_TO_DATE didn't become available until 4.1.1.

Comment: was a mysql 4 problem. I've since moved the database to mysql5. I'm still having some issues though. See my edit for info.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
STR_TO_DATE('2011,9,2','%Y,%c,%e') AS HelpDate
```

`%m` and `%d` assume formatting with leading zeroes, i.e. numbers that are always two digits long. Thus `STR_TO_DATE('2011,09,02','%Y,%m,%d') AS HelpDate` would probably work. `%c` and `%e` refer to the variable-length numeric month and day respectively.